# Python3 i have been geting this errer [TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not NoneType]

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def getKeyDict(csv_reader, key_position):
    key_dict = {}

    row_counter = 0
    unique_records = 0
    for row in csv_reader:
        row_counter += 1
        if row[key_position] not in key_dict:
            key_dict.update({row[key_position]: row})
        unique_records += 1

    # My use case requires a lot of checking for duplicates 
    if unique_records != row_counter:
        print ("Duplicate Keys in File")

    return key_dict
```

Comment: This is not a [MCVE], as it omits critical information about how it is called, and where the arguments come from.

Answer (score 1):

The error could be in the caller of getKeyDict() not supplying the second parameter `key_position` evaluating to `None`

Comment: They *have* to supply it, but if it's supplied as `None` it would exhibit this error.